# BigInt doesn't generate enough primary keys for a given table

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Disregarding the unrealistic nature of generating 18446744073709551615 rows on a given table in a database. Let's say it happens. Would you be able to maintain data integrity, if you had to create a second table to continue to store the same data you want to reference.

Comment: What's the specific database?

Comment: A SQL table with 1^19 rows *is* unrealistic in many other ways, so this is hard to disregard.

Comment: Consider using a UUID instead.

Comment: This is a faq. (And can be expected to be.) Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: The question is not that unreasonable.  Identity columns on parallel systems often have gaps -- and a gap of 1,000,000 is not unreasonable for future systems.  Not all ids are stored in a table, but are generally associated with operations of some sort (such as failed transactions).  I can imagine systems where even bigints would not be big enough.  However, it is a bad question for StackOverflow because what happens obviously depends on the database and the configuration of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there just limitations which must be dealt with. Sometimes you just need to document that limitation and move on. So create your sequence and document the limitation. So

```
create sequence long_range_sequence
       minvalue   -9223372036854775808
       no maxvalue
       start with -9223372036854775808
       increment  1;
comment on sequence long_range_sequence is  
        'Warning: Excessive Usage. Created on May 2020. If values are constantly used at the rate of 10M/sec ranges values will run out sometime July 60473.'
```

And let maintenance deal with it later. Of course by then it might be a moot issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which database you are using so I'll give you some options:

1. Some databases can provide you UUIDs that can overcome this limitation since they provide 128-bit values.
2. If you are using PostgreSQL database, then you can have multiple 64-bit IDENTITY (auto-generated) columns. If you use them cleverly you can have more than 2^64 values.
3. If you are using Oracle you can generate values up to 10^27 using sequences.